# Resize partitions from back unallocated partitions

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I want to resize my home and root partitions from a back partition or move the unallocated space forward. GParted is unable to do it.

Screenshot of partition table from GParted:

[image: Screenshot of GParted]

Comment: I see *padlock* symbols, meaning the partition is LOCKED because it's in-use or mounted.  You need to `umount` first (which is easiest by using a *live* system)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because your system is accessing it.

You need to boot from a usb flash drive and then change it using gparted.